# Send a custom e-mail without php. Weebly

Tags: javascript, html, weebly

My friend recently asked me to make a widget for his site that basically serves as a questionnaire. That thing is, his site runs on weebly. He wants the results of each questionnaire to be e-mailed to his account. I could easily do this with php but weebly doesnt support server side scripting.

Any ideas how can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into integration with a mailing service like Mail Chimp, etc? Mailing services will have an HTTP API that you can hook into.

Comment: I'm completely new to weebly and it's third party libraries. I'll look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup a form on weebly. Weebly automatically emails the results of the form to you. It is impossible to custom make one without a server.

Comment: You could also use 3rd party form builders.